# Failed to resolve: com.mesibo.api:mesibo:1.2.84

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jcenter, mesibo

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.mesibo.api:mesibo:1.2.84.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mesibo/api/mesibo/1.2.84/mesibo-1.2.84.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mesibo/api/mesibo/1.2.84/mesibo-1.2.84.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mesibo/api/mesibo/1.2.84/mesibo-1.2.84.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.mesibo.api:mesibo:1.2.84.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mesibo/api/mesibo/1.2.84/mesibo-1.2.84.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mesibo/api/mesibo/1.2.84/mesibo-1.2.84.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mesibo/api/mesibo/1.2.84/mesibo-1.2.84.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.mesibo.api:ui:1.2.81
         project :app > com.mesibo.api:callui:1.2.81
         project :app > com.mesibo.api:callui:1.2.81 > com.mesibo.api:calls:1.2.81
```

Is this builds is exist on Jcenter or MavenCenter ?.

I have checked official documentation of mesibo,
https://mesibo.com/documentation/install/android/#install-mesibo-core-sdk

I am trying this demo,
https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android

Comment: Try to sync again. It should revert back to 1.2.70

Comment: its working before 3 hours, now failing lol. let me try this version

Comment: that's because of Bintray shutdown and the new repository in not syncing yet.

Comment: Yes your are right